# SAP HANA Android Push Payload when application is in background and gcmNotification is used doesn't trigger the app properly

Tags: android, push-notification, sapui5, hana

I send this message to the restnotification service to the Hana Cloud Plattform:

```
https://mobile-id.hana.ondemand.com/restnotification/application/de.company.myapp/

{
 "gcmNotification": {
     "title": "Android Title message",
     "body": "Android Body messages"
    },
   "alert": "Message i see on iOS devices",
   "badge": 1,
   "data": "{'mydata1':'true','mydata2':'more'}"
}
```

**On iOS everything works fine:**

1) When the app is in background and the user clicks the notification the app becomes active and ProcessNotification will be triggered.

2) When the app is in foreground ProcessNotification will be triggered.

3) When the app is closed and the user clicks the notification the app starts and ProcessNotification will be triggered.

**On Android however:**

1) When the app is in background and the user clicks the notification the app becomes active and ProcessNotification will **NOT** be triggered.

2) When the app is in foreground ProcessNotification will be triggered.

3) When the app is closed and the user clicks the notification the app starts and ProcessNotification will **NOT** be triggered.

**What works:** 
If i only send this:

```
{
   "alert": "Message i see on iOS devices",
   "badge": 1,
   "data": "{'mydata1':'true','mydata2':'more'}"
}
```

**Every three points work!** It will be triggered even if the app is closed or in the background. **But my problem is that i need gcmNotification for the title and the body.** Without it the title is always  the title from the app.

Does anyone know if i do something wrong or is this a bug from the SAP Hana Cloud Plattform? Thank you in advance!